# Is there a way to use __builtin_expect to mark multiple switch statement members as likely?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17

In recent versions of gcc `__builtin_expect` can be used to mark a specific switch member as more likely than the others.  An example taken from their unit tests:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void
f(int ch) {
  switch (__builtin_expect(ch, 333)) {
    case 3: puts("a"); break;                                                 
    case 42: puts("e"); break;                                                 
    case 333: puts("i"); break;                                                 
    } 
}
```

Is there some way to mark multiple case statements in a switch statement as likely?

Comment: Does it have to be C++17? This has been standardized in C++20 with `[[likely]]` which can be applied to each individual label or statement in the branch.

Comment: Fwiw, gcc accepts the C++20 attribute `[[likely]]` even in C++17 mode.

Comment: @user17732522 I am specifically targeting C++17, however I was unaware that gcc supports `[[likely]]` in C++17.  Although I am interested in the question as asked since it's clear how you would do this with `[[likely]]` decorating the actual case specifiers instead of the switch specifier.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You also need to make sure that it works as intended or whether documentation explicitly states the support (in any given compiler version). According to the standard non-supported attributes shall be ignored, so it is up to the a potential compiler warning whether or not it will notify you about an unsupported `[[likely]]`.

Comment: @Chuu I haven't tried it, but is it necessary to use `__builin_expect` directly as condition in the `switch`? I expect that's not the case, so something like `__builtin_expect(ch == 33 || ch == 42, true);` before the `switch` might work.

Comment: @Chuu OK, nevermind. Putting it before the `switch` it seems to simply be ignored. It is even ignored when used as a subexpression in the condition.

Comment: Does it help to put the `case` statements in order of 'likelyness'?  You could check at Godbolt.

Comment: @user17732522 _"You also need to make sure that it works as intended"_ - I would expect anyone making suboptimizations like this to actually watch the result anyway, so whether using `__builtin_expect` or `[[likely]]`, the analysis of the effect would be very similar.

Comment: @PaulSanders I was experimenting with this, and for larger switch statements it pulls the likely case out to explicitly check for it and uses a jump table for the remaining cases.  Which obviously you could do yourself as well for multiple likely cases, but it would be nice to lean on the compiler here.